# How to solve Reporting Services's error

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-2008

I created report using reporting, but i am dizzy for case below

here are my query result :

```
___________________________________________________________________
Col1      | Col2             | Col3   | Col4          | Col5
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Budget01  | Description 1    | $2300  | Commitment 1  | $1000
Budget01  | Description 1    | $2300  | Commitment 2  |  $100
Budget01  | Description 1    | $2300  | Commitment 3  |  $600
Budget01  | Description 1    | $2300  | Commitment 4  |  $200
Budget02  | Description 2    | $5000  | Commitment 5  |  $500
Budget03  | Description 3    | $1000  | Commitment 6  |  $200
```

and i want result in Reporting Services like this :

```
___________________________________________________________________
Col1      | Col2             | Col3   | Col4          | Col5
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Budget01  | Description 1    | $2300  | 
          |                  |        | Commitment 1  | $1000
          |                  |        | Commitment 2  |  $100
          |                  |        | Commitment 3  |  $600
          |                  |        | Commitment 4  |  $200
Budget02  | Description 2    | $5000  | Commitment 5  |  $500
Budget03  | Description 3    | $1000  | Commitment 6  |  $200
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
SUB TOTAL                      $8300  |               | $2600
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Please find a col3's sub total is as i want $8300
```

But in actual, why are reporting services do to summary total is equals = $15200
How should i solve this problem?

Thank you for your advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [add a Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169987%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and then [find out the subtotal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms170114%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: the total should be equal $8300, but an actually its total equal $15200

Comment: Make sure that for total, you are using the correct Expression: `=SUM(Fields!Col5.Value)`

Comment: I guess, a reporting service do calculate all records from query result,that's mean not by grouping.

Comment: yes, i've checked it out after seeing this post. couldn't find a way. You can make a view from that table, and take also that view as data source, which will be grouped by 'col1' and 'col3'. then add its column corresponds to 'col3' and find subtotal. please, let me know if there is an easier way.

Comment: yes i think so, it is an easier way (make a view as a data source). Thank's